# How to place Icon Next to Label in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this label and would like to place an image directly to the left of it but I'm having trouble trying to do so.

[image]

This places the image above the label.

```
<Image Source="orders_icon.png"/>
<Label Text="Orders" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#845cd6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="10" />
```

This places the image and label on the same line but the label is too far to the right.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="orders_icon.png"/ Grid.Column="0">
    <Label Text="Orders" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#845cd6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="10" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why the asp.net tag? The question is not related to asp.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="orders_icon.png"/>
    <Label Text="Orders" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#845cd6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="10" />
</StackLayout>
```